# How to secure Redis Keys?

Tags: redis, jedis

Is there any way to secure redis keys, even the person who knows redis-server password that can not access or see redis keys.

I need this security because i am storing session in redis keys.
For each user there is unique key which is stored in redis as key.

If user knows keys then he can access any account.

Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you give anyone else access to redis?

Comment: Hi chris. I am storing user's session id on redis keys. And any of the user don't have access to that. There should be some mechanism to restrict keys access.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem you're trying to solve? If the users don't have access to redis why do you need to secure anything beyond having a password set for redis?

Comment: As i already said i am storing session id as redis key, why should anybody can see those keys. Let me tell you in details: From redis-cli if i can easily get all keys for each users. if i put those keys in client cookies i can easily get anyone's session. So redis keys should be encrypted or some security mechnism to access keys.

Comment: Assuming you are using redis auth, you and your application are the only ones with access to that data, your users can only access what your application permits them to access.

Comment: redis server password is shared among multiple users, for start and stop service and other configuration. Now i want nobody from them can even see redis keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124321/discussion-between-chris-tanner-and-hardik-patel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hash key, e.g. `md5`, for each session id, and take the hash key as *Redis key*.

```
// set
session_id_md5 = md5(session_id)
redis.set(session_id_md5, value);
```

When you want to get session info from Redis, re-create the hash key with session id, and search Redis with the hash key

```
// get
session_id_md5 = md5(session_id);
redis.get(session_id_md5);
```

Comment: @HardikPatel since these keys are encrypted, it doesn't matter whether redis-cli can get these keys. right? If someone uses redis-cli to get these encrypted keys, they cannot put these keys to cookie. And your keys are safely protected.

Answer (score 2):

Redis isn't designed to be used the way you are using it so this isn't possible, you should move your authentication up a level to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Redis doesn't provide any ACLs, so restricting access to `KEYS` command for certain clients isn't possible without some additional middleware. But if you want to just disable `KEYS` command, add following line to your redis config:

```
rename-command KEYS ""
```

You probably should also disable `MONITOR` and `CONFIG` commands:

```
rename-command CONFIG ""
rename-command MONITOR ""
```

Comment: Thanks. The users which has access to redis-cli can easily change this configuration and access the keys. But thanks for suggestion. i really unaware of rename-command.

Comment: AFAIK, as long as users don't have access to `redis.conf` file and `CONFIG` command is disabled, they shouldn't be able to change configuration using redis-cli. But I could be wrong.